# Have dynamic (as in changing/updated e.g, a blog page) links contained inside a div open in that same div

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the below script that grabs the links inside the div (scrollbox) and as you can see it is set to have the links open in a new window. I need to have them open in the div they come from within the original page. Can I do this with this script? If not what should I be using?

```
function Init()
{
    // Grab the appropriate div
    theDiv = document.getElementById('scrollbox');
    // Grab all of the links inside the div
    links = theDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // Loop through those links and attach the target attribute
    for (var i=0, len=links.length; i < len; i++) {
        // the _blank will make the link open in new window
        links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }
}
window.onload = Init;
```

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Do you mean the DIV contents should change according to the contents of a web page? If so, AJAX might be appropriate.

Comment: @pimvdb Sort of but not really. The contents of the DIV will be updated periodically but the contents should only change once a link is clicked. Hence I cant just input the link and set it a static target. I have to use the script above to 'grab' any links in the DIV and set the target of those links, what ever they may be at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But if I'm not wrong the target is not a window but a DIV element? Because in that case, you would need some AJAX technique so as to load data without refreshing the current page (or use an `iframe`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the pages the links refers to, but in the current page, you should consider using the `<iframe>` tag.

But maybe i don't understand fully what you need

Comment: Yeah you're on the right track, but I want to avoid using <iframe> due to compatability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Look into JQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="webpageContainer"></div>

$( "#link" ).click( function()
{
    $( "#webpageContainer" ).load( $(this).attr( 'href' ));
});
```